# Dropdowns/Select with changing list of items

Tags: dropdown, validation, select, api

I have "dropdowns" and "select inputs" that are fed from a remote endpoint. The list of items coming from the endpoint changes over time, so it's possible that an option selected some time ago is no longer available as of a more recent date.

I still need to let users go back in time and edit a former element. But I am unsure how to handle the fact that and old item selection made sense back in that time, but not anymore.

What is the best user experience when a user edits an old document with a no longer valid option in a dropdown/selector?

1. Preserve the outdated selection just to keep the story consistent.
2. Force the user to pick a new element from the currently valid selections.

Comment: curious, what value would the document have if the option was no longer valid? i think that's something to think about to - what do you do with old documents when options change?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the old selection and notify the user with an inline error/warning that the current selection is not valid anymore. Maybe you can also add an option to get more information why it is not valid anymore (some technical details so the user understands what he/she can do better next time).

[image]